# Get a specific part from an String Array

Tags: java, android

Here a value from a `JSONObject` :

```
["MON-FRI 9:00AM TO 8:00PM","SATURDAY 8:00AM to 9:00PM","SUNDAY Closed"]
```

I want to save it in an Array of Strings and if I address for example:

```
Log.e("String:", s[0]);
```

I want to apear only: `MON-FRI 9:00AM TO 8:00PM`
No other characters. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's JSONArray so you can use [`getString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#getString(int)) or [`optString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#optString(int)) to fetch string data using index

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
//or
//JSONArray arr = yourJsonObject.getJSONArray("name");


String add = arr.optString(0);
```

Comment: @AndreiNechita i am glad that i could help, happy coding